# Animation where only specific part, at specific intervals is shown

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I have two issues.

1) The animation flicker while it playes, which I cannot understand since I have set a boundery box for each of the drawings in the script

2) After some time the animation will start to delete the first played part of the animation. (I would like to keep the entire animation when it is finished playing)

kind regards
Jesper

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz,animate}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}   %used for the item box around

\begin{document}

    \newcommand\neuronX{3}%
    \newcommand\neuronY{8.5}%

    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % static objects shared by all frames
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{xlrbox}{staticElems}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[use as bounding box,red] (0,5) rectangle (15,12);
        \draw [thick] (0,5) rectangle (15,12);

    \draw[] (1.6,6.8) rectangle ++(0.1,3.5);
    \draw[] (1.2,8.6) rectangle ++(0.1,1.7);
    \draw[] (1.4,7.9) rectangle ++(0.1,2.4);
    \draw[] (1,9.0) rectangle ++(0.1,1.3);

    \node[] at (10.5,9.5) {Channel 1};
    \node[] at (10.5,8.5) {Channel 2};
    \node[] at (10.5,7.5) {Channel 3};
    \node[] at (10.5,6.5) {Channel 4};

    \node [circle,draw,fill = red] at (\neuronX,\neuronY) (N1) {};
    \node [circle,draw,below right = 1cm and 0.8cm of N1,fill = green] () {};
    \node [circle,draw,below right = 2.2cm and 0.2cm of N1,,fill = blue] () {};
    \coordinate (A1) at (2.5,10);
    \coordinate (B1) at (2,6);
    \coordinate (A2) at (4 , 10);
    \coordinate (B2) at (4.5 , 6);

        % save bounding box coordinates
        \coordinate (LowerLeft) at (current bounding box.south west);
        \coordinate (UpperRight) at (current bounding box.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{xlrbox}%
    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % two shaded objects
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{xlrbox}{shaded-1}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[use as bounding box,draw] (LowerLeft) rectangle (UpperRight);
        \shade[top color=orange,bottom color=orange,middle color = red,fill opacity=0.4] (A2) to [bend right=10] (B2) to [] (B1) to [bend right=10] (A1) to (A2);
        %\node[yshift = 10.5cm,xshift = 7.5cm] () {Light Pulse};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{xlrbox}%
    %
    \begin{xlrbox}{shaded-2}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[use as bounding box,draw] (LowerLeft) rectangle (UpperRight);
        \shade[top color=white,bottom color=white,middle color = white] (A2) to [bend right=10] (B2) to [] (B1) to [bend right=10] (A1) to (A2);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{xlrbox}%
    %
    % the empty graph to start with
    \begin{xlrbox}{mygraph}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[use as bounding box,draw] (LowerLeft) rectangle (UpperRight);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{xlrbox}%
    %
    % putting the animation together
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{8}
        \xusebox{staticElems} %first frame showing only the static objects
        \newframe
        \gdef\oldyOne{9.3}%
        \gdef\oldyTwo{8.3}%
        \gdef\oldyThree{7.3}%
        \gdef\oldyFour{6.3}%
        \multiframe{80}{rx=4.9+0.05}{%
            % set line colour, vertical graph displacement and which shaded
            % object to use
            \def\whichShaded{shaded-2}%
            \def\dy{9.3}%
            \def\dyTwo{8.3}%
            \def\dyThree{7.3}%
            \def\dyFour{6.3}%

            \def\nOne{0}%
            \def\nTwo{0}%
            \def\nThree{0}%
            \def\nFour{0}%


            %light          
            \ifdim 5.3pt < \rx pt\relax%
            \ifdim  5.6pt > \rx pt\relax%
            \def\whichShaded{shaded-1}%
            \fi%
            \fi%
            %neuron 1
            \ifdim 5.5pt < \rx pt\relax%
            \ifdim  5.6pt > \rx pt\relax%
            \def\nOne{-0.4} 
            \fi%
            \fi%    

            \ifdim 6.3pt < \rx pt\relax%
            \ifdim  6.4pt > \rx pt\relax%
            \def\nTwo{-0.4} 
            \fi%
            \fi%

            %neuron 1
            \ifdim 6.3pt < \rx pt\relax%
            \ifdim  6.6pt > \rx pt\relax%
                \def\whichShaded{shaded-1}%     
            \fi%
            \fi%


            \ifdim 6.5pt < \rx pt\relax%
            \ifdim  6.6pt > \rx pt\relax%
            \def\nOne{-0.4}      
            \fi%
            \fi%    

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\oldx}{\rx-0.05}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0.1*rand}%

            % assemble the graph
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\oldx}{\rx-0.05}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0.1*rand}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yTwo}{0.1*rand}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yThree}{0.1*rand}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yFour}{0.1*rand}%

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\chOne}{\dy+\nOne+\y}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\chTwo}{\dyTwo+\nOne + \nTwo+\yTwo}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\chThree}{\dyThree   + \nThree+ + \yThree}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\chFour}{\dyFour     + \nThree +  \yFour}%


            \begin{xlrbox}{mygraph}%
                %repeat previous graph
                \makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{mygraph}}%
%               %
%               %append new line segments
                \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
                \path[use as bounding box] (LowerLeft) rectangle (UpperRight);
%%              
                \draw (\oldx,\oldyOne) -- (\rx,\chOne);         
%               
                \draw (\oldx,\oldyTwo) -- (\rx,\chTwo);
%               
                \draw (\oldx,\oldyThree) -- (\rx,\chThree);
%               
                \draw (\oldx,\oldyFour) -- (\rx,\chFour);
%               
%%              
                \end{tikzpicture}%
            \end{xlrbox}%
            \xdef\oldyOne{\chOne}%
            \xdef\oldyTwo{\chTwo}%
            \xdef\oldyThree{\chThree}%
            \xdef\oldyFour{\chFour}%
            %
            % shaded object in the background
            \makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{\whichShaded}}%
            %
            % overlay the static objects
            \makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{staticElems}}%
            %
            % put graph in the foreground
            \xusebox{mygraph}%
        }
    \end{animateinline}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks more like a `tikz` question, about how to draw the images shown above. The code you have posted draws something completely different. Please first try to build something on your own and then ask a question about a specific problem you may have encountered.

Comment: The issue is the only way I have figured out to do it is to use the  \makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{beam} where the beam is either white or colored depending on the binary case it should be} where the beam is defined at the top of my script. The issue at you pointed out xsavebox is not large enough to contain the entire animation :(

Comment: The code i would normally use is                                                   
\makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{\beam}}%" The beam"" 

%%overlay the static objects%%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{staticElems}}% the figures that does not change
   %
%%put graph in the foreground %%
\xusebox{mygraph}% The animation is being drawn by this called

Comment: When I compile the code (and add some default `\def\linecolor{black}` somewhere to get rid of the errors), the outcome is not anywhere close to the picture you post. What is the relation between the code and the image? Wouldn't it be better if you used to screen shot of an actual output to indicate what you want to do?

Comment: It my failt... I made a mistake regarding how I should present the problem.... I will upload a new code. Which I hope will lower the misunderstanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this does what you want?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz,animate}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,positioning,shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% writing timeline file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newwrite\TimeLineFile
\immediate\openout\TimeLineFile=neuron.txt
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,80} {
    % appending `x0' to transparency number --> keep all them all visible
    \immediate\write\TimeLineFile{::\i x0}
}
\immediate\closeout\TimeLineFile
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \newcommand\neuronX{2.5}%
    \newcommand\neuronY{9.5}%

    %starting points of curves
    \def\dy{9.3}%
    \def\dyTwo{8.3}%
    \def\dyThree{7.3}%
    \def\dyFour{6.3}%

    \def\oldyOne{9.3}%
    \def\oldyTwo{8.3}%
    \def\oldyThree{7.3}%
    \def\oldyFour{6.3}%

    % putting the animation together
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,timeline=neuron.txt]{8}%loop
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % static objects shared by all frames
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,6) rectangle (14,11);

        \draw[] (1.6,6.8) rectangle ++(0.1,3.5);
        \draw[] (1.2,8.6) rectangle ++(0.1,1.7);
        \draw[] (1.4,7.9) rectangle ++(0.1,2.4);
        \draw[] (1,9.0) rectangle ++(0.1,1.3);

        \node[] at (10.5,9.5) {Channel 1};
        \node[] at (10.5,8.5) {Channel 2};
        \node[] at (10.5,7.5) {Channel 3};
        \node[] at (10.5,6.5) {Channel 4};


        % save bounding box coordinates
        \coordinate (LowerLeft) at (current bounding box.south west);
        \coordinate (UpperRight) at (current bounding box.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \newframe
        \multiframe{80}{rx=4.9+0.05,dimx=4.9pt+0.05pt}{%
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            % line segments
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            %
            \def\nOne{0}%
            \def\nTwo{0}%
            \def\nThree{0}%
            \def\nFour{0}%
            \def\lighto{4}% 
            \def\lightt{4}%
            %
            \def\linecolor{black}% 
            \ifdim 5.3pt < \dimx\relax%
            \def\linecolor{red}%    
            \ifdim  5.4pt > \dimx\relax%
            \def\nOne{-0.4}%
            \fi%
            \fi%
            %
            \ifdim 6.3pt < \dimx\relax%
            %\def\linecolor{green}%
            \ifdim  6.4pt > \dimx\relax%
            \def\nTwo{-0.4}% 
            \def\lighto{10}% 
            \def\lightt{10}%
            \fi%
            \fi%
            %
            \def\myopa{0}%
            \ifdim 6.3pt < \dimx\relax%
            \ifdim  6.6pt > \dimx\relax%
            \def\myopa{0.4}%
            \fi%
            \fi%
            %
            \ifdim 6.8pt < \dimx\relax%
            %\def\linecolor{blue}%   
            \ifdim  6.9pt > \dimx\relax%
            \def\nThree{-0.4}%   
            \fi%
            \fi%
            %
            \ifdim 7.1pt < \dimx\relax%
            %\def\linecolor{red}%    
            \ifdim  7.2pt > \dimx\relax%
            \def\nOne{-0.4}% 
            \fi%
            \fi%
            %  
            \ifdim 7.5pt < \dimx\relax%
            %\def\linecolor{red}%    
            \ifdim  7.6pt > \dimx\relax%
            \def\nOne{-0.4}%
            \fi%
            \fi%
            %
            % assemble the graph
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\oldx}{\rx-0.05}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0.1*rand}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yTwo}{0.1*rand}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yThree}{0.1*rand}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yFour}{0.1*rand}%
            %
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\chOne}{\dy+\nOne+\y}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\chTwo}{\dyTwo+\nOne + \nTwo+\yTwo}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\chThree}{\dyThree   + \nThree+ + \yThree}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\chFour}{\dyFour     + \nThree +  \yFour}%
            %
            %new line segments
            \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, draw=\linecolor]
            \path[use as bounding box] (LowerLeft) rectangle (UpperRight);

           \draw (\oldx,\oldyOne) -- (\rx,\chOne);         

            \draw (\oldx,\oldyTwo) -- (\rx,\chTwo);

            \draw (\oldx,\oldyThree) -- (\rx,\chThree);

            \draw (\oldx,\oldyFour) -- (\rx,\chFour);

            \node [circle,draw,fill = red] at (\neuronX,\neuronY) (N1) {};
            \node [circle,draw,below right =  1cm and 0.8cm of N1,fill = green] (N2) {};
            \node [circle,draw,below right = 2.2cm and 0.2cm of N1,,fill = blue] (N3) {};
            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \fill[red,fill opacity=\myopa,preaction={fill=white,fill opacity=1}] 
             ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=2mm]N1.north west) 
             -- ([xshift=2mm,yshift=2mm]N1.north east)
             -- ([xshift=2mm,yshift=2mm]N2.north east)
             -- ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-2mm]N2.south east)
             -- ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-2mm]N3.south east)
             -- ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm]N3.south west)
             -| cycle;           
            \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}%
            %
            \xdef\oldyOne{\chOne}%
            \xdef\oldyTwo{\chTwo}%
            \xdef\oldyThree{\chThree}%
            \xdef\oldyFour{\chFour}%
        }
    \end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

The time interval in which the background is visible is determined by

```
            \def\myopa{0}%
            \ifdim 6.3pt < \dimx\relax%
            \ifdim  6.6pt > \dimx\relax%
            \def\myopa{0.4}%
            \fi%
            \fi%
```

There are many other ways to do this but here I am using the `backgrounds` library to fill something on the back. Could be simplified.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!!! (sorry for the late acceptence of your answer)